# RasterVis levelplot in R with scale bar

Tags: raster, r, levelplot

I'm using the rasterVIS package in R to create maps with levelplot, which works fine. But I cannot figure out how to add a spatial scale bar to the maps. Does anyone know?

Comment: The axis labels serve to show the spatial scale. Are they not enough?

Answer (score 2):

There is a code example for adding a spatial scalebar in the FAQ section of rasterVis:

https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#scalebar

```
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

levelplot(r) +
  layer({
    xs <- seq(181000, 181400, by=100)
    grid.rect(x=xs, y=330500,
                  width=100, height=30,
                  gp=gpar(fill=rep(c('transparent', 'black'), 2)),
                  default.units='native')
    grid.text(x= xs - 50, y=330560, seq(0, 400, by=100),
              gp=gpar(cex=0.5), rot=30,
              default.units='native')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
library(sp)
layout.scale.bar()
```

which works with lattice's levelplot:

http://www.dpi.inpe.br/gilberto/tutorials/software/R-contrib/sp/html/spplot.html